# Would  to use AJAX to get an option from the database and use it in a jquery setup or is there an alternative to consider?

Tags: theme-development, jquery, ajax, theme-options

I have a slider in my theme. I have a setting in the options which controls whether that slider is set to "slide" or "fade". This slide/fade setting is in the jquery and of course the options setting is in the database. I presume the normal method of getting this setting is via AJAX but I thought I'd ask as I have a number of other similar scenarios on this theme.

I always think of AJAX as meaning "change data without having to re-load the page" .... but in this case I just want jquery to have access the data when the page is first loaded ... so it seems my "understanding" is a bit off and jquery is needed for **any time** javascript/jquery needs to get info from the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enqueue the script as you would normally, & then call the JS function right after the slider HTML output (or on `wp_footer`), and pass a JSON config back to the function.

```
<!-- slider HTML -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( "#my_slide" ).mySlider(
        <?php echo json_encode( $my_config /* array or object of arguments */ ) ?>
    );
</script>
```

**Alternatively**, enter [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script):

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-slider', plugins_url( 'js/slider.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_localize_script( 'my-slider', 'My_Slider', array(
    'somevar' => get_option( 'my_var' ),
));
```

This'll output in the head something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">My_Slider = { "somevar": "value of get_option( 'my_var' )" }</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/my-slider/js/slider.js"></script>
```

See how you now have access to the  JS global `My_Slider`?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use wp_localize_script to pass PHP variables to your javascript.

In your javascript file you can reference the variable as such:

```
myCustomVariable.fadeOption
```

Then in your options panel you can assign $_POST['fade_option'] to myCustomVariable.fadeOption:

```
function load_fade_option(){
  wp_enqueue_script('slider', 'slider.js', array( 'jquery' ));
  wp_localize_script('slider', 'myCustomVariable',
    array(
            'fadeOption' => $_POST['fade_option'],
         )
    );
}
```

Pippin has some good documentation on this:

http://pippinsplugins.com/use-wp_localize_script-it-is-awesome/